# Concatenate vectors on NA positions

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R made up of several columns.

I find my self in this situation. x1 and x2 are two columns and i need to concatenate them in one column as shown clearly in my example

```
x1 x2 
NA  3
NA  4
 1  NA
 2  NA

x_new
 3
 4
 1
 2
```

I tried this command

```
x1[which(is.na(x1))]<-x2[which(is.na(x1))]
```

But i'd like to find something more elegant, and in particular a solution involving `dplyr` package.

Thanks

Comment: Arguably `x1[is.na(x1)] <- x2[is.na(x1)]` is more elegant and obviates involving `dplyr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways: (wrap `data.frame(x_new = ...)` around if a data.frame is wanted.)

```
rowSums(df1, na.rm = T)

apply(df1, 1, na.omit)
```

---

```
df1<-
structure(list(x1 = c(NA, NA, 1L, 2L), x2 = c(3L, 4L, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code

```
 zz = data.frame(X1=c(NA,NA,1,2),X2 = c(3,5,NA,NA),stringsAsFactors = F)

 mod_zz = cbind.data.frame(zz, newcol=c(na.omit(c(t(zz)))))

> mod_zz
  X1 X2 newcol
1 NA  3     3
2 NA  5     5
3  1 NA     1
4  2 NA     2
```